# How to treat 0x40010006 exception in vectored exception handler?

Tags: windows, exception

I register my own vectored exception handler, to catch and trace various exceptions in my application.

Sometimes I get an exception having 0x40010006 code, which is thrown by `OutputDebugString` function. Certainly, I'd like just to ignore it. What would be the appropriate return value in this case: `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION` or `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find exception codes listed in the ntstatus.h SDK header file.  This one is DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_C, some likelihood that you typed Ctrl+C to trigger it.

Exception codes with values less than 0x80000000 are just informal and never an indicator of real trouble.  In general, you should never mess with exceptions that you don't recognize and don't want to explicitly handle.  Let Windows continue searching for a handler by returning EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH, the debugger will probably catch it in this case.

Comment: How do you know that codes with values less than 0x80000000 are informational only? I'm just trying to understand where I can read more about the code space. Thanks.

Comment: @RussCox I think he got them from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485841(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION is not equivalent to catch(...), because it will continue execution from the same address where exception happend. Actually you could fix cause of exception and go back to program execution.

Comment: Now we also have 0x4001000a for wide version: DBG_PRINTEXCEPTION_WIDE_C